# How to distinguish between left and right mouse click on mousedown event in Google Map API v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The mousedown event of Google Map API v3 gets fired on left and right click both, how can I identify whether it is right click or left click.

I am new to Google Map API, I was using Virtual Earth API until now, where I was able to distinguish between left and right mouse click on mouse down like e.leftMouseButton returns true if it is left click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `mousedown` use simply `click`.

For right click event you can catch `rightclick` event this way:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "rightclick", function(event) {
  /* do something on right click */
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zuds3/198/)

---

To distinguish what button was pressed using `mousedown` event you can use `event.which` parameter. But for that, the handler should be added to DOM element (canvas), since Google API doesn't provide `which` option in event object.

```
var c = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
google.maps.event.addDomListener(c, "mousedown", function (e) {
    if (e.which === 1) {
        $("#click").text("Left click");
    } else if (e.which === 2) {
        $("#click").text("Middle click");
    } else if (e.which === 3) {
        $("#click").text("Right click");
    }
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zuds3/199/)

Comment: Okay, but is there any way to distinguish it on mousedown?

Comment: @HariChaudhary It's possible, but not reliable. For left click you have to use `click` and for right click `rightclick`. You can listen for `mousedown` on DOM element and check `e.which`. See update.

Answer (score 0):

It's a long time after the question was raised, but I've just been working on a tool for a Google maps application where I wanted to initiate a process on right-mouse down, continue the process while dragging, and then end the process on right-mouse up.

So, I eventually got the right-mouse down event by using a DOM listener on the map canvas to store which button had been pressed to a global variable, and using an ordinary Google maps listener on the map object to fire another function, but with a short timer to ensure the DOM listener had properly written to the global. Something like:

```
var cvs = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
google.maps.event.addDomListener(cvs, 'mousedown', function(event) { getMouseBtnFromDomListener(event); }); 
google.maps.event.addListener(mainMap, 'mousedown', function(event) { setTimeout(function() { initFooEvent(event); },30); });

function getMouseBtnFromDomListener(evt) { 
  // 1=left, 2=middle (not recognized with my mouse), 3=right...
  mButton = evt.which;   // global var
}
```

Works well enough for me...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var _key = (window.Event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
```

example:

```
var c = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
google.maps.event.addDomListener(c, "mousedown", function (e) {
    var _key = (window.Event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if (_key === 1) {
        $("#click").text("Left click");
    } else if (_key === 2) {
        $("#click").text("Middle click");
    } else if (_key === 3) {
        $("#click").text("Right click");
    }
});
```