# Google Maps event listener does not get removed

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm having trouble understanding why the `setgeometry` event inside my `mouseup` event keeps firing after `rightlick` event... even though I do remove the `setgeometry` event listener.

```
drawLayer.addListener('mouseup', function() {
    changedGeom = drawLayer.addListener('setgeometry', function(e) {
        console.log('got new geometry');
        google.maps.event.removeListener(changedGeom);
    });
});

drawLayer.addListener('rightclick', function(e) {
    console.log('deleted polygon');
    google.maps.event.removeListener(changedGeom);
});
```

The reason why I have `setgeometry` inside `mouseup` is because I only want the last position of the polygon. Otherwise it will record every move.

Maybe I'm over complicating this, but here's what to do to reproduce the problem:

1. Open the console and drag the polygon on the Google Map. You should see *got new geometry* message once.
2. Now rightclick on your mouse and you should see the message *delete polygon*.
3. Now move the polygon again. You will see that the `setgeometry` event keeps firing, resulting in plenty of *got new geometry* messages.

I'm unsure why this is happening. Can someone explain?

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8ueq6spu**

Comment: If you `console.log` the `mouseup` event you'll see it's triggering twice. This means you declare two `geometry_changed` listeners, then only remove the last one. Why does `mouseup` fire twice? Don't know, but it has been mentioned before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490151/google-maps-api-v3-click-event-firing-twice

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Weird that it fires twice. Shouldn't adding `google.maps.event.removeListener(changedGeom);` on 2 separate lines remove both then? I guess not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out why this is happening to you.

I removed your `rightclick` listener to see that an event was still being triggered on a right click action, then I realised it is because both left click and right click result in a `mouseup` event.

So in your current implementation the listener is being removed on the `rightclick` press/event, but a new instance is created as soon as the button is released due to the `mouseup` event.

To fix this behaviour you could opt for a standard `click` instead of `mouseup`, however, I also noted that this event does not fire when you drag the boundary nodes (which is probably why you used `mouseup` in the first place).

A quick fix would be to still use the `mouseup` event, but detect which type of click the event originated from e.g.

```
drawLayer.addListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    if (e.which === 1) {
        console.log("Left click");
    } else if (e.which === 2) {
        console.log("Middle click");
    } else if (e.which === 3) {
        console.log("Right click");
    }
});
```

- Adapted this solution from : [How to distinguish between left and right mouse click on mousedown
  event in Google Map API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26397686/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-on-mousedown-event-in-goog)

Comment: Thanks Philip. I am looking at this solution right now. It looks like it may work well.